# Typescript: 'Follow' conditional type

Tags: typescript

Is there any way Typescript can infer `b` to also be of type `U extends Foo ? string : number`? If `a` is of type `U extends Foo ? string : number` then in the true branch adding a number to string would result in string. In the false branch, adding a number to number would end up being a number. Thus I'd expect the type of `b` to also be inferred to `U extends Foo ? string : number`. Or is it a wrong assumption?

When I run the snippet below I get the following error:

> Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'U extends Foo ? string : number' and 'number'.(2365)

```
interface Foo {
  propA: boolean;
  propB: boolean;
}

declare function f<T>(x: T): T extends Foo ? string : number;

function foo<U>(x: U, d: number) {
  const a = f(x);
  const b = a + 2;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=12&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIAOU6hAggFzIBGmANhHCANz5EmEBCVt6DTrAL65cAEwgI6cKChgBXEAjDB0IZDAA8AFQB8ACgAeVLQEpjyCAcghRAZzSZkAfmS2wUUAHNkVEHIC21NCsuPKKyqrqmBoAqvpGyDEANMiivgFBUCY4bAiqbshwyAC86oYmrAR5IAXUJYXIANTIAExCuEA)

Comment: The error is there to tell you that you shouldn't add a number to a string.

Comment: You can add a number to a string. That results in a string. Typescript has no issues with that: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBAXjAvDAjAbgFCkrAJkmAckMy3GhgEMCEBqGXNIA)

Comment: Not with unions: `function add(s: string | number) {
  return s + 1;
} // Error`

Comment: `a` is of a conditional type, not a union type

Comment: Just dont - https://dev.to/macsikora/this-is-why-typescript-restricts-operator-i0f

Comment: Conditional types and unions behave similarly. Also this: https://dev.to/macsikora/this-is-why-typescript-restricts-operator-i0f

Comment: It's about branches, not unions really. `b` should end up the same type as `a` in my view and no error should be thrown

Comment: Its about union, at level of `foo` the result of `f` is always union. And the operation `+` after is or concatenation or addition.

Comment: `a` is of a conditional type, not a union! That's why I would expect typescript to infer the same type for `b`

Comment: Lukasz, conditional type in `f` has nothing to behavior of `foo`. For `foo` constant `a` is either string or number, it depends from what will be x, therefor TS is considering that as union at this level. It would not be union if for example you would restrict `U` to be one of branches, and then `f` would return only one type.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to strict behavior of `+` operator in TS. TS will never allow for using `+` in situation where the result can be more than primary type `string` or primary type `number`. Function `foo` is using `+` in such a way, that the result type is union `string | number`, as the function is polymorphic and if the argument `x` extends `Foo` then we will get `string` if not `number`.

Conditional type presented at level of `f` is not evaluated to the final type in `foo`, is not, as we have type variable `U` at this level. It would be evaluated to specific type if type would be given explicitly like in below examples:

```
// types provided directly
const x =  f(1) // number
const y = f({propA: true, propB: false}) // string

function inside<U>(a:U) {
  const x =  f(a) // T extends Foo ? string : number // not evaluated
  return x + 1; // error
}

function insideButExactBranch<U extends Foo>(a:U) {
  const x =  f(a)
  return x + 1; // ok no error
}
```

In `foo` we still work with unknown `U`, that is why result of `f` is considered as any possible, that means - `string | number`. And if so the `+` cannot be compiled.

In other words - TS cannot evaluate the result of `f` function, therefor it takes the all possible types of return from the conditional type, what means union `string | number`. More about why using `+` is restricted in TS here - [Why TypeScript restricts + operator](https://dev.to/macsikora/this-is-why-typescript-restricts-operator-i0f)

Answer (score -1):

Typescript reports an error here not because the Javascript code will fail at runtime, but because according to the type annotations this code sometimes does string concatenation, and other times does arithmetic, and this usually means the programmer has made a mistake.

When you write `+` you almost always intend either that it means string concatenation, or you intend that it means arithmetic, but you rarely intend that it could mean both. So, this is an error to warn about code which is probably wrong.

If you really want a `+` that sometimes does string concatenation and sometimes does arithmetic, you can add a `@ts-ignore` comment before that line. This is similar to `@SuppressWarnings` in Java; you're telling the compiler not to warn you about something which usually indicates a mistake, because *in this case* it's not a mistake and you don't need the compiler to warn you about it.

```js
function foo<U>(x: U, d: number) {
  const a = f(x);
  // @ts-ignore
  const b = a + 2;
}
```

Comment: `a as any` is also ugly but at least language construct

Comment: Is there any actual benefit of writing `a as any` instead? Type assertions should normally be used for where Typescript does not know the correct type (usually when it infers a weaker type than possible by other reasoning) and the programmer knows the correct type. In this case, Typescript *does* know the correct type of `a`, so the programmer and compiler don't disagree about its type, they disagree about whether "sometimes concatenate, sometimes do arithmetic" is a mistake. So I would use `@ts-ignore` here because it better corresponds with the reason for overruling the compiler.